# Huachicol para robo de gasolina

Tags: selección-de-palabras, etimología, modismos, méxico

Ahora en México se habla mucho del Huachicol de gasolina.  Según este [interesantísimo artículo](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-america-latina-46831943) sobre este asunto en la BBC en español la palabra viene de la palabra maya "huaach" o "waach" y tiene varias acepciones:

1. Extranjero
2. Ladrón
3. Bebida alcohólica

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿se refiere esta palabra más al acto de robar la gasolina o más a la acción de extraerla con la boca (chupar)?

¿O los dos, por igual?

Comment: Karlomanio, deshaz mis edits si no quedaron bien.

Comment: Tus edits no están mal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo a [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huachicol)

> El *huachicol* o *guachicol* es una bebida alcohólica adulterada. **Esta palabra del español mexicano también se usa para nombrar al combustible (gasolina o diésel) adulterado o robado**. Las personas que se dedican a la actividad ilícita de robar y adulterar combustible y bebidas alcohólicas en México se conocen como *huachicoleros*

Así que parece que se llama así a la gasolina robada o adulterada<sup>1</sup>, o al acto de robarla y/o adulterarla, en lugar de a la forma de extracción o robo de la misma.

En la entrada para [huachicolero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huachicolero) leemos sin embargo respecto al origen que

> Según el Diccionario del español de México, huachicol o guachicol tiene dos significados principales: es aquella persona que se dedica a bajar fruta de los árboles usando *un cuachicol o huachicol, que es una vara larga que lleva en un extremo una canastilla* y es el ‘delincuente que se dedica a robar gasolina perforando los oleoductos que la conducen’.

que puede aumentar la confusión respecto a si la forma de extracción u obtención del producto robado tiene que ver con el nombre.

En la entrada sobre la etimología de la palabra en [etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?huachicolero), leemos que

> Pero esta actividad ilícita [de adulterar el alcohol] pronto pasó al negocio de los combustibles y el término nominal **huachicol** comenzó también a significar 'combustible **adulterado**' o también ¿Porqué no? 'combustible **robado**'.

La palabra se refiere a la gasolina robada o adulterada como si fuera alcohol adulterado, y por tanto la palabra se refiere más al acto de robarla o adulterarla, que a la forma de extracción o robo.

---

1. El combustible adulterado se diluye con diferentes substancias para lograr un mayor beneficio financiero al venderlo y puede causar el desperfecto de los automotores en los que sea utilizado.

Comment: Gracias @Diego por su respuesta muy bien explicada.